# Convert std::vector of one type to another type

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to convert simple vector of ints to vector of my custom class. My class has a constructor that accepts int.

```
class BitInteger {
public:
    BitInteger(int num) {
    // code omitted
    }
};
```

I have tried the following code, but it returns some esoteric errors, how can I fix it?

```
std::vector<int> nums {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
std::vector<BitInteger> bitIntegers(nums.size());
bitIntegers.assign(nums.begin(), nums.end());
```

The error is:

```
no matching constructor for initialization of 'BitInteger'
            ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
```

How can I change my constructor so it worked, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pay attention to the line numbers on your error messages. The problem isn't in the `assign` call; it's on the initialization of the vector.

When creating `std::vector` of a certain size, the vector is filled with default-constructed elements. `BitInteger` is not default-constructible, so you can't make a vector containing `nums.size()` of them. Provide a default constructor to make the code compile.

```
BitInteger() {
  // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can directly construct the elements from the previous vector.

```
std::vector<BitInteger> bitIntegers(num.begin(), num.end());
```

Then you can skip the whole empty initialization step. (Thanks @Tas for this suggestion)